# Chrome app , javascript issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

In the chrome app I have some js/files.js that are being loading in the index.html and others html.

I was using:

```
 "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "index.html",
      "width":800,  
      "height":800

    }
  },
```

but it is deprecated and going to be removed from webstore chrome  this month.

I've changed as it recommend, with :

```
"app": { "background": { "scripts": ["main.js"] } },
```

and there it is calling the index.html
when I've made this change , javascript did not work anymore. Can't figure it out what is happening.
I've tried and read every kind of issue with chrome app and javascript files, but cant run a simple function like:

```
 var index = {
 initialize: function () {        
    setTimeout(function () {
        var user = null; 
        if (user == null) {
            window.location.href = "login.html";
        } else {
            //do something more
        }
    }, 500);
}

};
index.initialize();
```

from this js file

Comment: you have a trailing comma in your code above `}, 500); },`.

Comment: yes, again, it is a code I've pasted fast, sorry, I fixed that too. But as I said , javascript was working.

Comment: I would suggest reading the [runtime](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_runtime#event-onLaunched) and [window](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create) docs.

Comment: thanks I've readed them, but not find too much , I'm still stuck. javascript code is being loaded I guess, becouse inside initialize:function(){  } I am adding for example : document.querySelector('#greeting').innerText =
    'Hello, World! It is ' + new Date(); , and it is beeing displayed, but, something happens with some functions like setTimeout or  window.location.href that not are working, I can't figure it out what could be

Answer (score 0):

There is an unbalanced(extra) `}` in this snippet

```
"app": { "background": { "scripts": ["main.js"] } } },
```

Comment: Yes, it was just in the code I've pasted here, I've fixed that mistake

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manipulate `window.location` from App pages anymore, [among other things](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated).

Basically the idea is to have to use a single-page applications, or as a workaround you can open new windows with `chrome.app.window` as needed.

Comment: Yep, thats correct.I figure it out  that was the only issue too, every js works correct, and those you mentioned are the correct ways, so I am manipulating to use one  single index.html and redirecting other pages in this same index.

Comment: In case of a login a separate popup - as a stop-gap measure before you implement it as a single page app - wouldn't be a strange user experience.